# MSBuild v4.0 is not supported, aborting

Tags: visual-studio, ionic-framework, msbuild

I am developing ionic framework to build an Windows application. I can only add Windows platform, but I can't build it. When I build it, I get below error:

```
MSBuild v4.0 is not supported, aborting.
Error: AppPackages doesn't exists.
```

System Configuration:

- OS: Windows 8.1
- Visual Studio: 2013 ans 2015 installed
- Windows SDK: 8.1

Can anyone help?

Comment: Yes, I am also facing a same issue with command prompt installation point.

Comment: This is fixed, follow the bellow steps
1. cd ionic app dir.
2. ionic cordova platform add windows
3. ionic prepare platform windows
4. Add below section in config.xml
<platform name="windows">
        <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
    </platform>
 
5. open the ' CordovaApp.sln ' from appdir/platforms/windows/ in VS 2013/2015/2017 [Assuming you have the Visual studio set up for cordova build]
6. build it from  VS

Answer (score 5):

You don't have build tools.
Try with [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159)
 or [Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools).
For Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 look in visualstudio.com/downloads/ section "Other tools and frameworks".

Comment: +ONE just to get me to the right links for 2015 build tools

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I was trying to open the .sln file from Visual Studio it said me that the project as incompatible with that version. I have uninstalled Visual Studio and installed the required version for my project.

Inside the platforms/windows folder you will see a .sln file which in the name contains the version of Visual Studio you need, such as CordovaApp.vs2013.sln. Install that version and try again to build it.

Comment: I am having same issue and CordovaApp.vs2013.sln is there but its not available for download. Can I upgrade it to 2017???

Answer (score -5):

Your application package does not exist, also MSBuild 4.0 is not supported, try to upgrade your windows or rebuild your application.